# Can I order part of an SQL table that have the same value that is being ordered?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I know the question is a bit confusing and I just started learning SQL. But, if I'm ordering a two-column table and some rows have the same value in the ordered column, can I order those rows by a different column?

The table is a name | year table. I need to sort the table by year in descending order. Obviously, there's bound to be multiple rows with the same listed year. So, is there a way that I can sort those rows based on the name column?

Hopefully, this isn't too confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  `ORDER BY` can take multiple keys:

```
order by year desc, name
```

`name` is used only when more than one row has the same `year`.